# UITableView section index not able to scroll to search bar index

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uisearchbar

Prior to iOS7, we added a magnifying glass icon to the top of the UITableView index by prepending `UITableViewIndexSearch` to the section index titles.

By dragging to the magnifying glass icon in the section index, the tableView can scroll to the searchBar with the following code:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView sectionForSectionIndexTitle:(NSString *)title atIndex:(NSInteger)index {

    NSInteger resultIndex = [self getSectionForSectionIndex:index];

    // if magnifying glass
    if (resultIndex == NSNotFound) {
        [tableView setContentOffset:CGPointZero animated:NO];
        return NSNotFound;
    }
    else {
        return resultIndex;
    }
}
```

However in iOS 7, this would only scroll to the first section instead of the search bar.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To solve this we adjusted the content offset to account for the UITableView's content inset introduced in iOS 7: `CGPointMake(0.0, -tableView.contentInset.top)`

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView sectionForSectionIndexTitle:(NSString *)title atIndex:(NSInteger)index {

    NSInteger resultIndex = [self getSectionForSectionIndex:index];

    // if magnifying glass
    if (resultIndex == NSNotFound) {
        [tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0.0, -tableView.contentInset.top)];
        return NSNotFound;
    }
    else {
        return resultIndex;
    }
}
```